# Customizing swagger static resources with Springdoc

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-ui

According to the documentation (see the link below) the static resources can be customized with Java by extending SwaggerIndexPageTransformer and overriding the transform method.

https://springdoc.org/#customizing-swagger-static-resources

As I understand the following files could be customized:

index.html

swagger-ui-bundle.js

swagger-ui.css

swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js

swagger-ui.css.map

swagger-ui-bundle.js.map

swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js.map

favicon-32x32.png

According to the example code I can check the name of the resource like:

```
if (resource.toString().contains("swagger-ui.css")) {
...
```

My problem is the only resource handled by this method is "META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/4.10.3/index.html"

Anybody had the same issue or do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I upgraded Spring to 2.7.0 and the issue disappeared.